# Python: fail to execute gpiozero Button command inside Class

Tags: python, pigpio

while this code succeeds:

```
def press_on():
            print('press')

        HWButs = gpiozero.Button(21)
        HWButs.when_pressed = MainApp.init_buts.press_on
```

inside a class, pressing the button does not execute `press_on`

(irrelevant code is croped out ):

```
class MainApp:
    def __init__(self,master, pins,ip):
        self.frame1= LabelFrame(master,text='Hardware Display',padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame2= LabelFrame(master, text="Buttons")
        self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column= 0, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.HardWare = RemRelay(ip, pins)
        self.GUI = RemRelay_GUI(self.frame1,pins)
        self.SFButs = SwitchButtons(self, self.frame2,len(pins))
        #self.HWButs = ButtonSwitchRel(self, input_gpioPins,output_gpioPins)
        self.update_gui()
        self.init_buts()

    def init_buts(self):  ## here is where but is defined
        def press_on():
            print('press')

        HWButs = gpiozero.Button(21)
        HWButs.when_pressed = MainApp.init_buts.press_on


    def update_gui(self):
        self.GUI.get_state(self.HardWare.get_state())
        root.after(500,self.update_gui)



root = Tk()
output_gpioPins = [4,22,6,26]
input_gpioPins = [3,21,5,27]
ip = '192.168.2.113'
App = MainApp(root, output_gpioPins, ip )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suprisingly, the answer lies with preceding `self.` for all `pigpio` fuctions.
this is how it was tested: "A" class was created, with a `Button`,`LED`, and an `OutPut` device (Relay )`button` press, all 3 were activated correctly.

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep
import gpiozero

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.2.113')
        self.Relay= OutputDevice(13, pin_factory=factory,initial_value=False)
        self.led = LED(17)
        self.button = Button(21)
        self.led.source = self.button.values
        self.button.when_released = self.switchoff
        self.button.when_pressed = self.switchon


    def switchon(self):
        self.Relay.on()

    def switchoff(self):
        self.Relay.off()


Rel = A()
pause()
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.